# Curl responded with 401: Unauthorized even with username and password sent

Tags: curl, cmd

I have a batch script that uses curl to do a http-get request to a webserver in the network. Problem is in curl im getting a response of `401: Unauthorized` even if i send the username and password compared to just entering the link in a browser like google chrome which returns `200: OK`

```
C:\Users\myuser>curl -I "http://admin:admin1234@192.168.0.4/arg1=0&arg2=20&arg3=0"
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Login to 28b6e642501d12764d8430059585d39b", qop="auth", nonce="1592879309", opaque="ecd7f630cfdef2dec4aebb35f81708e84d20a755"
Connection: close
Set-Cookie:secure; HttpOnly
CONTENT-LENGTH: 0
```

I have also tried:

```
curl -I -u admin:admin1234 "http://admin:admin1234@192.168.0.4/arg1=0&arg2=20&arg3=0"
curl -I -u admin:admin1234 "http://192.168.0.4/arg1=0&arg2=20&arg3=0"
```

With the same result `401: Unauthorized`. I know it not a problem with the device im connecting to since if i use `http://admin:admin1234@192.168.0.4/arg1=0&arg2=20&arg3=0` in google chrome, the device operates as it should and it also returns with `200: OK`

Is there a different way of sending username and password, bonus if the username and password do not show up in any log files

Comment: Try enclosing the user:password in quote marks.  `"user:password "`  There is also `Authorization: Basic {base64string}` and
`Authorization: Bearer {token}`

Comment: This page lists many variations.  https://programming.vip/docs/use-a-curl-with-a-username-and-password.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The clue is in this response header field:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Digest
```

It means the server wants the client to use the **Digest** method, and not **Basic** which is the default method when `-u` is used.

Add `--digest` to the command line, or perhaps `--anyauth`.

Comment: --digest made it work ! Thank you